# How to find an optimum set of integers/coordinators where the distance between first and last coordinates will be the MINIMUM possible?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Team, after referring to various posts on StackOverflow, I am still NOT able to identify a solution for the following problem (which is a bit different and complex)

**Any help in finding the solution/algorithm (preferably in JAVA) will be highly appreciated.**

**Problem Statement :**

Consider a set of N groups, each having some number of points in a one-dimensional space. Each point is expressed by its coordinate on a line.

Write a program to choose exactly one point from every group to form a new set, such that the distance between first and last points in the new set is the minimum possible.

**Input:**
N sets of integers.

**For example:**

- [21, 1, 150, 289, -321]
- [160, 3, 30]
- [170, 22, 6, 7]

**Output:**
**The newly formed set of integers**.

**For example:**
[1, 3, 6]

Assumption : The input can be a standard inline input OR it can be a file with N lines representing N sets. **Ultimately, the input is N number of sets of coordinator-points/integers**.

**Test Cases :**

---

**Test 1**

Test Input

- 21, 1, 150, 289, -321
- 160, 3, 30
- 170, 22, 6, 7

Expected Output :
1, 3, 6

---

**Test 2**

Test Input

- -24, -77, 89, 29, -3
- 187, -99, 1

Expected Output :
-3, 1

---

**Test 3**

Test Input

- 6, 19, 95, 76, 24
- 79, 53, 2, 9, 16, 91, 73
- 81, 14, 65
- 22, 60, 37, 32, 99, 71

Expected Output :
**14, 16, 19, 22**

---

**Test 4**

Test Input

- -26 7 89 38 83 -90 87 87 59 66 0 81 -51 -45
- -52 23 37 -7 -16 -46 70 21 18 77
- -32 77 -47 -15 86 -5 38
- 64 32 53 78 -90 74 1 51 23 -95 -5 92 10 34 92 -70 37 -8 9 -64
- 4 74 87 -27 66 6 31 49 11 -59 91 98 59 -60 41 58 48 2 -1 90 23 -89 -45 -37 29 22 -66 -87
- 86 -69 0 -36 -43 33 -57 -44 21 28 -51 33 27 -56 43 -29 -33 -46 22 30 50 39 100
- -55 -40 40 30 89 -45 3 -34 -30 16 33 14 -98 -4 54 28 -14 11

Expected Output :
**37 37 38 38 39 40 41**

Comment: The first and the last should be close. What about the middle coordinate?

Comment: Thanks @NomadMaker for your response. If the First and Last would be closed, the middle coordinates/integers will also automatically be quite close w.r.t. each other. Pease have a look at the "Expected Output" part in some of the Test Cases that I have mentioned in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, don't just provide your task and let us give you the solution. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Assuming you don't have any idea what you need to do, I can give you a guideline what you could do. (I did not try coding this myself, this is only in my head what I would try to create)

- (Read the input)
- Figure the smallest value in the first group out and save that value
- Make a loop, starting in the first group, going over every group
- In your loop, start another loop, going over every point in your group
- Check if the current point is equal to your saved value from above
- If it is, go to the next group and add your value to a list
- If not, add 1 to your saved value and continue with the next point
- When both of your loops are done, you print the values in the list